# How do I delete a row of data using radio button (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

```
 <?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "user", "pass","mydatabase");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
           {
              echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
           }
              $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable");

        // create form
              echo '<form action = "deleteuser.php" method = "POST" name = "mydeleteform">';
              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo '<input type = "radio" style = "inline" name ="selectdelete">';
                echo "First name: ". $row["firstname"]. " Last name: ". $row["lastname"]. 
                     " Age: " . $row["Age"] . " Email: " . $row["email"]. " Phone number: 
                     ".$row["Phonenumber"]."<br>";
              } 
                echo '<input type = "submit" value = "DELETE" name = "submitdelete">';
                echo '</form>';
 ?>
 <?php ?>
```

So now this works, the main purpose of this php code is to pull data from phpmyadmin and display it in the browser.

Now I have a problem of displaying all data with each data having a radio button.

My objective is = if the use click the radio button it will delete the whole row of the ticked data. I tried but it only displayed deleted but actually it's still inside phpmyadmin's table.

Comment: so you want to delete selected row only?

Comment: Yes. Like I have data with 50 rows, User clicks the radio button on row 47, then data row 47 will be gone.Thus having only 49 left.

Answer (score 0):

Use an unique value for each radio button that is provide value to it like your DB table primary key

```
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
              {
                echo '<input type = "radio" style = "inline" name ="selectdelete"     value="'.$row['idOfYourTable'].'>"';
                //idOfYourTable is your primary key of table
                echo "First name: ". $row["firstname"]. " Last name: ". $row["lastname"]. 
                     " Age: " . $row["Age"] . " Email: " . $row["email"]. " Phone number: 
                     ".$row["Phonenumber"]."<br>";
              } 
                echo '<input type = "submit" value = "DELETE" name = "submitdelete">';
                echo '</form>';
                ?>

            **deleteuser.php**

        $selectedRow=$_POST['selectdelete'];
```

And delete row from table where idOfYourTable=$selectedRow like-

```
        $sql="DELETE FROM TABLE WHERE idOfYourTable='$selectedRow'";
```